# Keyboard repeat not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, system-settings

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, I changed some language settings (from 'English US' to 'Hindi' and then back to 'English US'), during which I think I did something wrong but could not remember what.

Now key repeat is not working, means if I want to type any letter multiple times then I have to hit that key multiple times i.e. if I want to scroll down in a document by 20 lines then I have to hit the 'scroll down' key 20 times, key repeat it is not working.

Can some body help me to figure out which setting I've changed and how to restore it and is there any way to restore all system/user settings to their default value?

Answer (score 7):

Go to `system settings >> keyboard` and make sure that `repeat` and `speed` are set correctly.

Comment: The setting was correct but keyboard repeat still didn't work. SOLVED by disabling repeat and enabling it again.

Comment: I found that once after a vnc session (which doesn't support auto repeat) that when I got physically back to the machine that repeat was no longer working. Just updating the keyboard setting fixed it - there was no indication it was disabled.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 18.04, somehow the settings works the other way around :

1. Dragging Speed to the left completely, sets it to disabled
2. Dragging Speed a little, sets it to fast repeat
3. Dragging Speed to the right makes it slow (or normal)

Toggling the On/Off button seemed to fix it too.

PS : Config found in `Settings > Universal Access > Typing`

Comment: Happened to me on ubuntu 18.04 after an x11vnc session.
Playing around with the Universal Access / Typing did the trick.