# keyboard repeat is working improperly

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

When I hold a key down, only several characters appear on the screen. In order to delete for example a sentence or few words, I need to press backspace many times.

I'd like to restore default behavior when you can hold a key and receive something like "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr...", but now I have only "rrr" or in some cases "r". How can I achieve that?

I've tried solutions from here [Keyboard repeat not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260637/keyboard-repeat-not-working), but it's not working for me. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

UPDATED: when I press Alt+F1 I can see that a new signal ^@ appears every second without any actions from me. I think that can cause the problem because it interrupts my keyboard holding. But I don't know who is sending that and why? Even when I unplug keyboard and mouse that signal is still appearing.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948 the portion to remove `peaq_wmi` driver.

Answer (score 0):

disabling peaq_wmi has helped me, you can find out how to do it here [Touchpad gestures and holding keys does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948)